# Tableview Cell Images Moving To Different Positions When Scrolling

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

When I scroll the table view my images move to the wrong cells. I have set some conditions when an image should be showing or not showing, but no matter what I have tried they just keep moving. My code below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellID = @"myCell";

    CustomTableView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];


    if (cell == nil) {
        if (self.view.frame.size.height == 736) {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCelliPhone6+" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        }
        else if (self.view.frame.size.height == 667){
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCelliPhone6" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        else if (self.view.frame.size.height == 568) {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCelliPhone5" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        }
        else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCelliPad" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        else {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableView" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

    }

     MusicFileInfo *musicFileInfo = [mMusicInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     cell.trackName.text = musicFileInfo.mDesc;
     cell.trackName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     cell.trackName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Regular" size:13.0];

    if (songPlaying == indexPath.row && mAudioPlayer.isPlaying) {

        [cell.playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pauseBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pause:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.playButton.tag = indexPath.row;

    }

    else  {
        [cell.playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playPreview:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.playButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    }



    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pack%li", (long)indexPath.row]] == true || [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"unlockAllTracks"] == true) {

        cell.rightImage.image = nil;


    }

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pack%li", (long)indexPath.row]] == false) {
        if (indexPath.row <= 4) {
            cell.rightImage = nil;

        } else

        [cell.rightImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iapBtnStore.png"]];

    }


    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:231.0f/255.0f green:235.0f/255.0f blue:236.0f/255.0f alpha:1];
    cell.tag = indexPath.row;
    return cell;

}
```

The play button and track label are fine, they work as they should, but the rightImage is where the problem is.

The first 5 cells should not have an image on first load, on second load the first 5 cells should have a star image and the rest of the cells should have a padlock image. After an IAP has been made, depending on the indexpath.row then that padlock image should no longer be there.

I am checking that with NSUserDefaults.

I hope I have explained properly.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by "first load" and "IAP has been made"?

Comment: Though I will need more details regarding it, but my hunch is that you need to do cleanup in your CustomTableView (cell). 
override :prepareForReuse method of UITableViewCell class and set 
self.rightImage = nil in it. 
This method is called when your cell gets reused (or recycled) and you can ensure to do any sort of cleanup in it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`UITableViewCells` get reused to increase memory efficiency and performance, so you need to "reset" any elements that might change based on the item's state or it might re-appear somewhere else in the list.

Hence "reusable":
`[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];`

```
if (cell == nil) {
  // load nib if needed
}
cell.rightImage = nil; // always reset image
```

Comment: Thank you mate, I have it sorted :)